# Why do I have to alias bower when I use zsh with oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, bower, oh-my-zsh, prezto

On [bower.io](http://bower.io/) there is a warning that says:

> Warning
>
> On prezto or oh-my-zsh, do not forget to alias bower='noglob bower' or bower install jquery#1.9.1

I didn't see this before and I'm already working in a project where I have to use bower install, and everything looks normal so far.

I'm pretty curious about it, why is that, should I worry?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`#` is used for [pattern removal](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html) in zsh *(see the "Standard forms: pattern removal" section)*.

Either alias it with `noglob` or quote `'jquery#1.9.1'` every time.

Comment: Good answer. Shouldn't be a problem if you always add packages to your dependency file before installing.